# Thread inside a Loop? SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can something like  [#pragma_omp](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Fcompiler%2Fref%2Fruompplf.htm) ([OpenMP](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/openmp.html)) in C for loops

```
#pragma omp parallel for    
for (ii = 0; ii < nrows; ii++){      
  for(jj = 0; jj < ncols; jj++){       
    for (kk = 0; kk < nrows; kk++){
       array[ii][jj] = array[ii]kk] * array[kk][jj];
    }
  }
}
```

be applied to a loop in SQL Server?

```
WHILE (...) BEGIN
END
```

Something to paralelize the loop, using threads, How??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In a store procedure I am inserting lots of registries, so I would like to paralelize this, something to control max workers..

What you should do instead is to reformat the work as a SET based task, such as using UPDATE/INSERT into a temp table with the calculations/manipulations encapsulated on a pre-row basis.  SQL Server can then parallelize the query as it sees fit.

To control the max workers, have a look at `OPTION MAXDOP`

Comment: do you have an example, to follow your idea?

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server you should use a SET based solution not loops, SQL is a SET based based language. You could use [Parallel LINQ (PLINQ)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx) to parallel some of the stuff if running from outside SQL Server

Comment: In a store procedure I am inserting lots of registries, so I would like to paralelize this, something to control max workers...

Comment: SQLMenace is spot on - only use looping as a last resort, or if the requirement is truly trivial.